# Left margin not resettable -- Alternative option?

Tags: margins

I am a novice in LaTeX and I have problems with the left margin of a book document. Is there a way to reset the document's margin? I always have a small margin on the left side which I only can reset by setting the `hoffset` to a negative range. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\usepackage[top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=20cm]{geometry}
\title{bbbbbbbbbb}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm} 
\setlength{\voffset}{0mm}  
\author{blah}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test.jpg}
\newpage
fhaiushfaoishf
\newpage
\layout
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to reset the margin?
Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You are telling LaTeX that the margins are zero. Use `left=2cm` and your left margin will be two centimeters.

Comment: i want them all to be zero. but the left margin is still about 3mm.

Comment: the `preview` document class will strip all margins.  (Why would you want length 0 margins?)

Comment: Remove the `layout` package (and `fullpage` that doesn't do anything good in this context).

Comment: You are mixing a class (`scrbook`) and a number of packages (`fullpage`, `geometry`) that each offer ways to change the page layout. Stick to only one package. And try to get your result with `scrbook`. It's probably easier to start from zero than from some more or less broken template you found somewhere else on the Web.

Answer (score 4):

Your text is flush left but you are seeing the paragraph indent and you only have two one line paragrphs so no text goes flush left.

add

```
fhaiushfaoishf

\noindent X\dotfill X
```

[image]

You could add

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

Comment: i didn't knew that there is an default indent. thanks a lot for that hint. that solves it! thanks!